# How to use youtube-api ver 3 sample files of .net?

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to develop web application which use  youtube api v3 for searching videolist by channel name and author name.

for simple testing 
go to youtube api client site
then download sample files of .net.

I downloaded  youtube/yt-samples-dotnet from [here](http://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-dotnet).
Here i got 4 class files.
no sln.

Then what to do? i mean just open it and run!!!?  or something else needed from my side coding?

I already create account and Generate API key.

UPDATE

Now i create new project 3 tier with BAL DAL PAL
In BAL : i added all 4 .cs files

then add reference which is download from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Downloads).

I need :

```
 using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
 using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3;
 using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data;
```

then what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the comment at the top of those files, there are dependencies on the [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/). You can follow the user guide for [getting started](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/GettingStarted), and I'd recommend using the [NuGet approach](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/Build#Using_NuGet) to pulling in the dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/youtube/v3

Then you can download the library opening the nuget webpage and viewing the package id and the version.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Google.Apis.youtube&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance
```

and then build this url:

```
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{packageID}/{packageVersion}
=>
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/1.7.0.94-beta
```